# Разъясните условия задания

Tags: массивы

Не совсем понятно по условию задачи, что хотят чтобы сделали.Прошу объяснить условия, что там хотят найти. Условие: в массиве А[1..6] найти сумму положительных элементов, которые  находятся в диапазоне от -1до 5 включительно.

Comment: Странная задача. Если складывать надо только положительные элементы, то тогда зачем дополнительное условие от -1 до 5?

Comment: Чтобы запутать.

Comment: Мне это тоже показалось странным. Может просто убрать это дополнительное условие или изменить на нормальное?

Comment: А может условие `A[i] > 0 && A[i] <= 5`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    int[] a = new int[6] ;

    // вводим/получаем/считываем значения

    // подсчитываем сумму
    int sum = 0 ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++ )
    {
        // отсекаем все кроме положительных
        if ( a[i] > 0 )
        {
            // проверяем попадает ли число в диапазон от [-1 до 5] 
            // нижнюю границу мы уже проверили т.е
            // разбили диапазон на: [-1; 0] U (1, 5]
            // поэтому проверяем только правую часть    
            if (a[i] <= 5)
            {
                sum = sum + a[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

у вас описание массива идет в начале задачи, а условие о том что числа (имеется в виду только позитивные) должны попадать в диапазон в конце, логично предположить что это требование относится именно к ним. это банальная проверка вашего логического мышления, ведь задача программиста искать и описывать закономерности:

```
        // как НЕ нужно делать
        if ( a[i] > 0 )
        {
            if ( -1 <= a[i] && a[i] <= 5 )
            {
                sum = sum + a[i] ;
            }
        }

        // как нужно делать
        if ( a[i] > 0 )
        {
            if ( a[i] <= 5 )
            {
                sum = sum + a[i] ;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double m[6];
double summa;
int i, kon;

int main()
{

    cout << "Vvedite chisla v diapasone ot -1 do 5" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        cin >> m[i];

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (m[i] > 0)
            summa = summa + m[i];
    }

    cout << "Summa = " << summa;

    cin >> kon;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем windows.h, stdafx.h и math.h? И вообще, не стоит мешать ученикам учиться на простейших задачах. Если они и их сами не осилят, то никогда ничему не научатся.

Comment: Вы правы, они не нужны. Это просто я из другой программы скопировал. Лень заново подключать каждый раз все эти библиотеки.
(Только  вот "stdafx.h" нужна, т.к. писал в VS)

Comment: для чего было выкладывать решение? Вы бы хоть нормально отредактировали код, а то лишний ввод и переменные. Нельзя было просто уточнить, что требуется найти сумму положительных чисел, и требуется вести числа в диапазоне -1 до 5.

Comment: Из решения сразу видны ответы на все вопросы.

Comment: Только это вредит учащимся, лень объяснить условия уже.

Comment: Молодец @НикиЧ , здорово догадался, только лишил @ArniLand удовольствия самостоятельно решить задачку.